# StyleFunctionProps in JavaScript (Chakra UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm unsure of how to implement StyleFunctionProps in my theme for Chakra UI in my NextJS project. The example in [Chakra's documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/customize-theme#customizing-single-components) is written in Typescript, however, I'm using Javascript. How would I go about implementing this example as Javascript?

The example (in Typescript):

```js
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import type { StyleFunctionProps } from '@chakra-ui/styled-system'

const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Button: {
      variants: {
        solid: (props: StyleFunctionProps) => ({
          bg: props.colorMode === 'dark' ? 'red.300' : 'red.500',
        }),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as in the example. You just need to remove the typing imports/annotations.

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Button: {
      variants: {
        solid: (props) => ({
          bg: props.colorMode === 'dark' ? 'red.300' : 'red.500',
        }),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

In addition, you can destructure the props parameter

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Button: {
      variants: {
        solid: ({colorMode}) => ({
          bg: colorMode === 'dark' ? 'red.300' : 'red.500',
        }),
      },
    },
  },
})
```